# Set text color in an Angular Material list in a sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following html:

```
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav opened="true" mode="side" class="sidenav">
    <mat-list role="list">
      <mat-list-item role="listitem" >Item 1</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item role="listitem" >Item 2</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item role="listitem" >Item 3</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
```

How can I set the colors of Item 1, Item 2, and Item 3 to something I want? (This may be a general problem of Material Lists regardless of where they are used.)

I have tried creating a class 'text-color' at each level and in a css file

```
.text-color
{
   color: white;
}
```

I have tried putting a style element in each mat-list-item.

In all cases the text remains black.

Comment: In your HTML, you can just directly target them too without creating a custom class. `mat-list-item { color: white }` would do the same. Be careful of encapsulation though because that CSS could apply to other items depending on how your files are setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `color` property of CSS to assign a colour to each mat-list-item as shown in this example; https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-sort-default-pan1cb?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.css

Comment: I did try that but it had no effect. Text remained black. I wonder if it is because I was in a sidenav?

Comment: I am now using mat-tree and have the same issue when my tree node is a button. I can use ```mat-tree-node
{
  color: #ee0;
}``` for non-button nodes. Button nodes are not affected.

Comment: I gave up on angular material and just did it myself using standard html and css. Much easier to understand, and I have full control, and it works.